# What ref tag do I use for draft.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, draftjs, use-ref

I'm using Draft.js for a form I'm building on Next.js with TS, and I'm running into some errors. Here is my code:

```js
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(
    EditorState.createEmpty()
  );
 
  const editor = useRef<**WhatDoIUseHere**>(null);
 
  function focusEditor() {
    editor.current.focus();
  }
 
  useEffect(() => {
    focusEditor()
  }, []);

return (
        <div onClick={focusEditor}>
      <Editor
        ref={editor}
        editorState={editorState}
        onChange={editorState => setEditorState(editorState)}
      />
    </div>
)
```

What "tag" do I use for the 6th line? `const editor... (null);`

Thank you!

Comment: What about <any> type :)?

Comment: `<Editor | null>`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/d974abb0c2844bf99724aba9448df42a63291e0e/src/component/base/DraftEditor.react.js#L445):

1. It is a div element, so you should use `HTMLDivElement`.

```
const editor = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

2. You should use `editorRef`, not `ref`.

```
<Editor
  editorRef={editor}
  // ...
/>
```